# Error R10 (Boot timeout) : Django app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have been trying to deploy a django app on Heroku. But it is always failing with the following error (R10 timeout, failed to bind to PORT in 60 seconds). The app works absolutely fine when deployed locally. I have been able to configure the postgres db correctly on heroku (bootstrapped the data and checked the contents). But somehow my web application is not starting, as can be seen in the logs below.

I have tried setting up explicit port number, as suggested in some forums. But it didn't work.

Any idea what's going wrong ?

I have put the heroku logs below. My code is here, if it helps : https://github.com/solitaryreaper/sp_mysiswrites

Thanks.

```
2014-02-25T06:38:08.220957+00:00 app[web.1]: 0 errors found
2014-02-25T06:38:08.225056+00:00 app[web.1]: February 25, 2014 - 06:38:08
2014-02-25T06:38:08.225056+00:00 app[web.1]: Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'sisnewsarticles.settings'
2014-02-25T06:38:08.225056+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
2014-02-25T06:38:08.225056+00:00 app[web.1]: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2014-02-25T06:39:06.941786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-25T06:39:06.942022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-25T06:39:08.171526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-25T06:39:08.179601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-25T06:39:11.684273+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/enews/ host=barkha-writes.herokuapp.com request_id=65c9cb99-c629-46b5-9dd7-fed5c9bfdc13 fwd="24.240.36.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Procfile according to documentation given on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django).
Also add gunicorn to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

your Procfile look like

> "web: gunicorn path/of/yourwsgit/file.wsgi"

your wsgi script look like this.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: Was finally able to make it work by adding gunicorn to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and modifying Procfile as follows "web: gunicorn <folder containing wsgi.pyc's name>.wsgi:application". Thanks for pointing me in the right direction !!